# I'm not sure how to solve the "CS5001" error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm very *very* new to C# and programming in general, so as a fun project I decided to create a login screen thing. But, I typed some code and I got the error code "CS5001" in visual studio. Any tips? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoginProject
{
    public class Users
    {
        string job;

        public static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I got the error code "CS5001"` Even we programmers don't know all error codes out of memory, so __please__ copy-paste the __full__ error message you're getting.

Comment: @tkausl CS5001"Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point LoginProject" is the full thing

Comment: Having gotten a solution, take a sec to carefully *read* the error message and see if it doesnt tell you exactly what was wrong.

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp
haha, I guess I glossed over that part when learning. Thanks

Comment: That's why the error message is important. C# error messages are amazingly descriptive (try out some SQL error messages sometime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs5001), you need a static 'Main' method (remember that C# is case sensitive, so 'main' is not going to work)

> This error occurs when no static Main method with a correct signature is found in the code that produces an executable file. It also occurs if the entry point function, **Main, is defined with the wrong case, such as lower-case main**

So, the solution is to replace your `main` function with `Main`